# Ввод символа в числовой тип данных

Tags: c++

Например, если я пытаюсь записать в `int` букву А, то программа падает. Можно ли как-то это отлавливать до того, как символ попадёт в переменную?

Можно конечно создать ещё один `char` и из него переводить в `int`. Есть ли другие способы?

Код:

```
while (true)
{
  int x,y;
  char Y;
    cout << "\nSelect X:";
    cin >> x;
    cout << "Select Y:";
    cin >> Y;
    y = (int)Y - 65;
    if (x > 9 || x < 0 || y>9 || y < 0)
    {
        cout << "Input error\n";
        continue;
    }
    if (comp[x][y] != 0&&comp[x][y]!='O')
    {
        cout << "Set failed\n";
        continue;
    }
    break;
}
```

Comment: А можно посмотреть на код, в котором запись символа в `int` приводит к падению программы?... 8-0

Comment: Это именно то место

Comment: А где объявления переменных и границы массива?

Comment: Если у вас `int Y`, и при вводе вы введёте символ `A`, то в Y будет 0, а потом вы из него вычитаете 65 и получаете отрицательный индекс `y`

Comment: Что вы хотите вводить в `Y` *в нормальном режиме*? Буквы? тогда его тип должен быть `char`. Но что-то мне подсказывает, что вы хотите вводить координаты, как в шахматной доске - типа B3 или F7. Нет?

Comment: да координаты.Ток с y всё нормально.Проблема с x

Answer (score 1):

С помощью cin вы не сможете присвоить инту символ, так как cin жден именно цифр, так что у вас в X Y остануться те же значения, что и были, а если вы позаботились о том, чтобы в них изначально не было мусора, то это будет 0 (ну или что вы там по дефолту поставили). Если уж хотите передовать символы, так сделайте X Y чарами, ну или воспользуйтесь сишной функцией scanf.

И да, если возьметесь вводить символы, то обязательно очищайте после ввода входной поток, так как \n - это тоже символ!!!

Answer (score 1):

Ну вот вариант ввода для шахматной доски - буква и цифра:

```
string buf;
cin >> buf;
if (buf.length() != 2) { cerr << "Error!\n"; exit(1); }
int x = toupper(buf[0])-'A';
int y = buf[1] - '1';
// Проверки корректности ввода - например,
if (x < 0 || x > 7 || y < 0 || y > 7) { cerr << "Error!\n"; exit(1); }
```

Вводите как одно двухсимвольное слово.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctype.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{    
    int n = 0;
    //cin.peek() это целочисленный тип текущего символа (int_type)
    while(!isdigit(char(cin.peek())))   
         cin.ignore();
    cin >> n;
    cout << n;    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Можно код выполнить в цикле, если хотите вводить еще, и программа будет читать только числа

Answer (score 0):

Если попытаетесь ввести в x не int, cin перейдет в состояние fail. Проверить это можно с помощью

```
if(!cin)
 //Обработка ошибки
```